# Google pay processing through stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I have implemented Google pay with stripe. Using the documentation provided by stripe. 
https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay
After the success of Google pay, the intent is passed to PaymentMethod of stripe and it is also successful. But I'm not able to see the payment in the Stripe payment section. I'm running in test mode using stripe demo PublishableKey.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without code, but note that completing the payment requires contacting your backend server and using a PaymentIntent. A PaymentMethod is just the card, it doesn't actually process a payment on its own. In the `onSuccess` function you'll need to integrate PaymentIntents https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android I'd suggest following that guide first, and coming back to Google Pay after completing a payment that way as it will be clearer how to proceed.